# jQuery UI - Accordion: set options in events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

```
$('.ui-accordion').accordion({
    // Event
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
        // How can I set an option here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All the jQuery UI widgets support an [`option` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option):

> **option( optionName, value )**
>   ***Returns: jQuery (plugin only)***
>
> Sets the value of the accordion option associated with the specified `optionName`.

So you should be able to:

```
$(this).accordion('option', ...);
```

to set an option.